# How to change date format from array

Tags: php, arrays, datepicker

**Now, I'm try to change date format from year-month-day to month/day/year form array.**

**I have an array that contains multiple dates in array i want to change each date format to year-month-day to month/day/year. Please check below array that contains multiple dates. Please help me if know something about that.**

```
Array
  (
    [0] => 2018-05-19
    [1] => 2018-05-20
    [2] => 2018-05-21
    [3] => 2018-05-22
    [4] => 2018-05-23
    [5] => 2018-05-24
    [6] => 2018-05-25
    [7] => 2018-05-26
    [8] => 2018-05-27
    [9] => 2018-05-28
    [10] => 2018-05-29
    [11] => 2018-05-30
    [12] => 2018-05-31
    [13] => 2018-06-04
    [14] => 2018-06-05
    [15] => 2018-06-08
    [16] => 2018-06-09
    [17] => 2018-06-10
    [18] => 2018-06-13
    [19] => 2018-06-14
    [20] => 2018-06-15
    [21] => 2018-06-17
    [22] => 2018-06-20
    [23] => 2018-06-21
    [24] => 2018-06-24
    [25] => 2018-06-28
    [26] => 2018-06-29
    [27] => 2018-07-02
    [28] => 2018-07-05
    [29] => 2018-07-11
    [30] => 2018-07-12
    [31] => 2018-07-15
    [32] => 2018-07-16
    [33] => 2018-07-17
    [34] => 2018-07-20
    [35] => 2018-07-23
    [36] => 2018-07-24
    [37] => 2018-07-25
    [38] => 2018-07-26
    [39] => 2018-07-27
    [40] => 2018-07-29
    [41] => 2018-08-07
    [42] => 2018-08-08
    [43] => 2018-08-10
    [44] => 2018-08-11
    [45] => 2018-08-12
    [46] => 2018-08-13
    [47] => 2018-08-15
    [48] => 2018-08-17
    [49] => 2018-08-18
    [50] => 2018-08-19
    [51] => 2018-08-20
    [52] => 2018-08-21
    [53] => 2018-08-25
    [54] => 2018-08-26
    [55] => 2018-08-27
    [56] => 2018-08-28
    [57] => 2018-08-29
    [58] => 2018-08-30
)
```

**I have an array that contains multiple dates in array i want to change each date format to year-month-day to month/day/year. Please check below array that contains multiple dates. Please help me if know something about that.**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you looking for a solution in PHP, or why did you tag this with datepicker?

Comment: these are comes from back end. In back end i have use multipledate picker.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<?php
$currentDates = [
    '2018-05-19',
    '2018-05-20',
    '2018-05-21',
    '2018-05-22',
    '2018-05-23',
    '2018-05-24',
    '2018-05-25',
    '2018-05-26',
    '2018-05-27',
    '2018-05-28',
    '2018-05-29',
    '2018-05-30',
    '2018-05-31',
    '2018-06-04',
    '2018-06-05',
    '2018-06-08',
    '2018-06-09',
    '2018-06-10',
    '2018-06-13',
    '2018-06-14',
    '2018-06-15',
    '2018-06-17',
    '2018-06-20',
    '2018-06-21',
    '2018-06-24',
    '2018-06-28',
    '2018-06-29',
    '2018-07-02',
    '2018-07-05',
    '2018-07-11',
    '2018-07-12',
    '2018-07-15',
    '2018-07-16',
    '2018-07-17',
    '2018-07-20',
    '2018-07-23',
    '2018-07-24',
    '2018-07-25',
    '2018-07-26',
    '2018-07-27',
    '2018-07-29',
    '2018-08-07',
    '2018-08-08',
    '2018-08-10',
    '2018-08-11',
    '2018-08-12',
    '2018-08-13',
    '2018-08-15',
    '2018-08-17',
    '2018-08-18',
    '2018-08-19',
    '2018-08-20',
    '2018-08-21',
    '2018-08-25',
    '2018-08-26',
    '2018-08-27',
    '2018-08-28',
    '2018-08-29',
    '2018-08-30',
];
$changedDates = array_map(function ($date) {
    return date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date));
}, $currentDates);
var_dump($changedDates);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        $dates = Array
          ("2018-05-19", "2018-05-20", "2018-05-21", "2018-05-22","2018-05-23");
        print_r($dates);
        $newDateFormat = array();
        foreach($dates as $date){
            $date = date('m/d/Y',  strtotime($date));
            array_push($newDateFormat,$date);
        }
        print_r($newDateFormat);
?>
```

I Think it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Arsalan Akhtar

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function convert_YYYYMMDD_to_MMDDYYYY($str)
    {
        return substr($str, 5, 2) . '/' . substr($str, 8, 2) . '/' . substr($str, 0, 4);
    }

    for ($i =0 ; $i < count($arr) ; $i++)
    {
       $arr[$i] = convert_YYYYMMDD_to_MMDDYYYY($arr[$i]);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Creative_0Q